# Reverse proxy does not work with https on ubuntu 20 using apache2

Tags: asp.net-core, apache2, ubuntu-server

I have a very simple Asp.net Core app that I published to my linux server.
The app works perfectly and I used `curl http://1270.0.0.1:5000` and  `curl https://1270.0.0.1:5001` to verify that.

I followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-5.0

`servername` is my domain

I can interact with my app from `http://servername` but I didn't get https to work!

`https://servername` returns 404

Here is my configuration (most of it is from microsoft link and the rest from some answers on stackoverflow):

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName servername.com
    ServerAlias *.servername.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
    ServerName servername.com
    ServerAlias *.servername.com
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    SSLEngine             on
    SSLProtocol           all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLHonorCipherOrder   off
    SSLCompression        off
    SSLSessionTickets     on
    SSLUseStapling        off
    SSLCertificateFile    /path/to/my/cert/file
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/ny/private/key/file
    SSLCipherSuite        ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 2 long days, I solved it by disabling the default config for apache.

Appartentlly I had 2 virtual hosts for 443.
The one I created and apache craeted a file `default-ssl.conf`

All I did was

1. Disabled the default config `a2dissite default-ssl`
2. Changed `ProxyPreserveHost` from `ON` to `OFF`
3. Added `SSLProxyCheckPeerName OFF`
4. And restarted apache `systemctl restart apache2`

Before you follow these steps, verify that you have the same problem by listing all files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. If you have more than one config to the same host and port, then you've the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

When you run Asp.net Core app on local. https work on localhost. and of you wrap  your localhost with webserver like (Apache/ nginx) https work for connection between your app and webserver. but your domain https work for client and your webserver need valid SSl or Free one like `letsencrypt`. to secure your client must install ssl on your apache.

for comminucate betwwn your app and webserver simple solution use only http (webserver didn't need ssl for map client http) and other solution install valid ssl for your localhost https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/.

[image]

Comment: I have a valid certificate on my domain and it works with no issues. There is no communication between the app and the webserver using https, I get 404. No errors in the log and I get only 404 info in access.log

Comment: I tried without SSL between the app and the webserver (reverse proxy) and I got an error message `AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /
`.
However I managed to solve it by just adding `SSLProxyCheckPeerName off` . I don't know why but it worked

Comment: @Niroda you must remove or comment all <VirtualHost *:443> block only keep <VirtualHost *:80>